# Using multiple connection strings for the same DBContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working on a asp.net core project which uses MongoDB and I am using dependency injection as well.

### How current system works

There is only one database and the connection string is saved in the appsettings.json. Some devices will be constantly sending data through the API to save it in the MongoDB database which works as it should :)

Now I have to enhance it, there will be multiple databases and data should be saved in the relevant database based on the API request (i will be getting the database name in the API request).

My question is how that can I change the database based on the API request? while using the same DbContext. It is not an option to create multiple DbContext.

I am somewhat new to MongoDb and asp.net core so any help or guidance is much appreciated.

This is my DbContext class

```
public class DbContext
{
    private IMongoDatabase _database;
    protected readonly MongoClient mongoClient;

    public DbContext(MongoSetting dbConnSettings)
    {
        var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(dbConnSettings.ConnectionString);
        var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(mongoUrl);

        mongoClient  = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);
        if (mongoClient != null)
            _database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbConnSettings.database);
    }...
```

Section of my StartUp class

```
services.AddTransient<CareHomeContext>();

services.AddSingleton(provider => provider.GetService<IOptions<MongoSetting>>().Value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your usecase correctly, it might be needed to use different databases in each request as well.

Hence I suggest to make database name as an optional parameter (so that you can use a default value from the configuration in case the database name is not provided in the request) to the `DbContext` class methods and create a method to get the database object (instead of getting it in the constructor) in the `DbContext` class as below.

```
private IMongoDatabase GetDatabase(string databaseName) => mongoClient.GetDatabase(databaseName ?? defaultDatabaseName);
```

Invoke the above method in each `DbContext` class method. e.g.

```
public async Task InsertAsync(string collectionName, Dictionary<string, object> fields, string databaseName = null) {
   var database = GetDatabase(databaseName);
   // Insert Code here
}
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. My only concern is will that open a connection every time when i call the GetDatabase method?

Comment: @GeshemW I suppose the database connections will be maintained by the `MongoClient` instance. Hence it won't be an issue with calling `GetDatabase` method multiple times. Please refer [MongoDB Driver Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/getting_started/quick_tour/) for more information.

Comment: @GeshemW I just verified your concern and noticed that `GetDatabase` method will just create a `MongoDatabaseImpl` object and the connection will be opened only on performing any CRUD operations.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try this

Comment: @GeshemW Sure. *Please consider marking the answer if it solved your problem.*